# Why do + and * evaluate to 0 and 1 respectively?

Tags: scheme, lisp

I'm using GNU/MIT Scheme:

```
1 ]=> (+)

;Value: 0

1 ]=> (*)

;Value: 1

1 ]=> (-)

;The procedure #[arity-dispatched-procedure 2] has been called with 0 arguments; it requires at least 1 argument.
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.

2 error> (/)

;The procedure #[arity-dispatched-procedure 3] has been called with 0 arguments; it requires at least 1 argument.
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 2) => Return to read-eval-print level 2.
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.
```

How come `+` and `*` are both evaluated to 0 and 1 respectively. And why evaluating `-` and `/` throws an error?

Is this part of the Scheme definition or is it an implementation detail in GNU/MIT Scheme?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reasoning behind this is that `+` and `*` have identity elements

```
1 * x = x * 1 = x
0 + x = x + 0 = x
```

While `-` and `/` have right identities, but as left associative operators this negates (pun!) their value. It makes sense to think about a variadic plus as a fold over a list of numbers with the initial element being an identity since mathematically, you can't differentiate this from just adding them together one by one. Furthermore, a fold over an empty list is just that seed element, the identity.

However since `-` and `/` lack identity elements, there is no sane default to return.

And it is a part of [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_278)

Comment: Division _has_ a right-identity value, it's `1`. Subtraction has a only a right-identity: `0`. So strictly speaking, they're not "lacking" identity elements

Comment: @ÓscarLópez But division and subtraction are left associative, making them ill suited for elements in a fold

Comment: @jozefg a left associative (foldl) or a right associative fold (foldr)?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Since they're left associative, you'd want a left fold. `(((3 - 2) - 1) - 0)`

Comment: @jozefg I meant, in response to your comment, which sort of fold are they ill suited for, actually.  Anyhow, it's also important to note that these operators, even though `-` and `/` don't accept zero arguments, they do accept one argument, and I think that's a palce that could be confusing. `(- 2)` => -2` but `(- 2 3) => -1` and `(/ 2) => 1/2` but `(/ 2 3) => 2/3`.  It's not strange, but there are really three cases: 0 args fails, 1 arg produces inverse, 2 or more args is a left associative fold with first arg as initial value.

Answer (score 2):

If you think of `+` or `*` in terms of a `fold`, or `reduce` you'll see they need a seed or accumulator value. For *, 1 makes sense. For + 0 makes sense. So you are getting back the seed/accumulator of a reduce.

It's also part of the spec.
http://gnuvola.org/software/guile/doc/Arithmetic.html#index-g_t_002a-487